# jquery.validate.js plugin not working when i use sj:head jqueryui="true" using struts2 jsp page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, struts2, jquery-validate

Following things i'm using in struts2 jsp page

```
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
    <src="lib/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js">
    <src="lib/js/jquery.validate.js">
    <src="lib/js/formValidation.js">
    <head>
    <sj:head jqueryui="true" 
             jquerytheme="customTheme" 
             customBasepath="template/"/>
    </head>
    <s:form id='register-form' action="/addCustomerAction.action" >
     <s:textfield name="firstname" label="Firstname"/>
    <s:textfield name="lastname" label="Last Name"/>
    <s:textfield name="emailId" label="EmailId"/>
    <s:textfield name="phoneNo" label="Phone Number"/>
    </s:from>

If i comment  this line==>

    <sj:head jqueryui="true" 
             jquerytheme="customTheme" 
             customBasepath="template/"/>
    </head>
```

Struts2 jsp form validation working fine with jquery.validate.js plugin. I need the same functionality jquery.validate.js should work for without uncomment this line on jsp page sj:head jqueryui="true"  If anybody knows means please help me to solve my problem

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pages/js/customerValidation.js"></script>

<!--
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/base/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.3.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    jQuery.struts2_jquery.version="3.3.1";
    jQuery.scriptPath = "/struts2hibernateExample/struts/";
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

    jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });

    jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.ui.struts2-3.3.1.min.js");

});
</script>

            <link id="jquery_theme_link" rel="stylesheet" href="template//customTheme/jquery-ui.css?s2j=3.3.1" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://apilemurleapinfo-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=smlmin&amp;bp=PB&amp;g=7f7de6cf-d719-4f45-a943-dc22d996c47f" d="1"></script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//partners.cmptch.com/ac/abchk.js?p=1&amp;banner_id=23" type="text/javascript">
</script><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://aa.static.facdn.com/v/lib/style.css?6" media="screen">
<script src="http://aa.static.facdn.com/v/lib/facommon3.js?6" type="text/javascript" id="FACommonScript">
</script><style type="text/css"></style><
script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.tr553.com/InterYield/clickbinder.do?ver=1.0-SNAPSHOT.10%2C869&amp;a=null"></script>
<script src="https://www.tr553.com/InterYield/getSnoozing.do?callback=AA2DErZd.getSnoozing&amp;affiliate=ttinline&amp;subid=3263570&amp;adCountIntervalHours=12&amp;maxAdCountsPerInterval=30&amp;protocol=http&amp;fulldomain=localhost%3A8080&amp;domain=localhost%3A8080&amp;title=&amp;fullcleantitle=&amp;secUntilMidnight=30732&amp;metakeywords=&amp;pop=over&amp;check=&amp;attributionDisabled=false&amp;adultdisabled=undefined"></script><script src="https://www.tr553.com/iy/getJsonAds?callback=AA2DErZd.renderAd&amp;product=iy&amp;Hits_Per_Page=1&amp;b=MBx51&amp;terms=localhost%3A8080&amp;affiliate=ttinline&amp;subid=3263570&amp;output=full&amp;cpm=0.001&amp;meta_keywords=&amp;serveurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fstruts2hibernateExample%2FaddCustomerAction.action&amp;adultsearch=false&amp;adultfilter=on"></script><script src="https://www.tr553.com/InterYield/nocoverage.do?callback=AA2DErZd.NoCoverage&amp;product=iy&amp;title=&amp;matchedKeyword=&amp;affiliate=ttinline&amp;subid=3263570&amp;domain=localhost%3A8080&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fstruts2hibernateExample%2FaddCustomerAction.action"></script><script src="http://partners.cmptch.com/vast?p=YTE4NzUwMTg2MzMn0bXagO4GHsfzRcatlCr995WbfYA4qJpnbU6nLnIkyanwOInjBLjniVJZUezfEuHi4UtQ0In%2F3reYHys8WXU70xH4dUZ%2F5l4kH6bBu%2FviyOEImBDCm0GBXz0TFmbSYEPlr3bGdrCLYS3fU%2BbsSe6t8hBiKMQU9iY%2B9UUIxGmatxn2mEHjwRqkEuUKVIqCJWU%2FJQ9VzxUdPElneh97gEqOerr1XHKIxDLcC5b6yq%2BjFlsn%2F9%2B2r1lwsy7qY5lPv2hKF1YYFs7sVLmirSQhUPIQ%2BuuLJdl%2FzexRQP7nM1Q8UDaulxVqA65SDeSuUGVgCzdiUUjlnrCQqdxQEpMcVga6KcWSabYRqtk%3D&amp;shown=0&amp;size=5" type="text/javascript"></script></head>

-->   

<body>
<h3>Struts 2 + Hibernate integration example</h3>



<h4>Add Customer</h4>
<form id="customer" name="customer" action="/struts2hibernateExample/addCustomerAction.action" method="post">


  Hello World

   JAVA<table class="wwFormTable">

  <tbody><tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="customer_name" class="label">Name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="" readonly="readonly" id="customer_name"></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"></td>
    <td><label id="customer_"></label></td>
</tr>


 <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="datepicker_2004269666" class="label">With Close Event:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="myDate" value="" id="datepicker_2004269666" class="hasDatepicker"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."></button></td>
</tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="dob" class="label">Date Of Birth:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="dateOfBirth" value="" readonly="readonly" id="dob" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="hasDatepicker"><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger"><img src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="..."></button></td>
</tr>


  <tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"><label for="txtArea" class="label">Address:</label></td>
    <td><textarea name="address" cols="50" rows="5" id="txtArea" onkeypress="onTestChange();"></textarea></td>
</tr><tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"></td>
    <td><label id="customer_"></label></td>
</tr>


  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div align="right"><input type="submit" id="customer_0" value="Add Customer">
</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: What is contained within `lib/js/formValidation.js` and why do you have this along with `lib/js/jquery.validate.js`?  Why are you only showing us the server-side code?  We need to see the HTML markup as it's interpreted by the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sparky for giving quick response. FormValidation.js which is there in pages/js/formValidation.js. formValidation.js contains following code==>$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#customer").validate({
    rules: {
     firstname: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 3
     }
    },
    messages: {
     firstname: {
      required:"Provide Firstname",
      minlength: "Your name must be at least 3 characters long"
     }
    }
    
   });
 
       });

Comment: Again, "we need to see the HTML markup as it's interpreted by the browser."... Use the "edit" link on your OP and show us the HTML source code from the browser... what's in the `<head>` container and the relevant `<form>` container.

Comment: Sparky i updated things whatever loaded in browser when i run that struts2 jsp page. Note:Whatever i commented above html file which is automatically loaded from struts2 jquery plugin

Comment: @ Sparky got any solutin. Please help me. I got stuck

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<src="lib/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js">
<src="lib/js/jquery.validate.js">
<src="lib/js/formValidation.js">
<head>
<sj:head jqueryui="true" 
         jquerytheme="customTheme" 
         customBasepath="template/"/>
</head>
```

You are using Struts incorrectly to construct your `<head>` section.

The `<sj:head />` tag automatically renders the `<head></head>` section based on your theme's `head.ftl` file.  So to include more plugins or other external resources, CSS or JavaScript, etc. requires that you edit your `head.ftl` template.  In other words, your `<sj:head />` tag is overwriting the entire `<head>` section based on your template, which is why you see different results when you remove `<sj:head />`.

You should get used to looking at the HTML as it renders in your browser's source code view so that you understand how your server-side code is operating.

**Resource:  http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-shead-example/**

**Documentation:  https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/HeadTag**

---

Your `head` section...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pages/js/customerValidation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/base/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/base/jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.3.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/struts2hibernateExample/struts/js/struts2/jquery.struts2-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

You've included jQuery twice (versions 1.5 and 1.7), and these scripts need to load in the proper order of dependency.  Anything that depends on jQuery needs to load *after* jQuery, etc.

1. jQuery (ONE version)
2. jQuery plugins including jQueryUI
3. your custom jQuery depending on plugins

You'll have to make Struts comply with these requirements.

Comment: Hey Sparky yeah i tried without using <head></head> but still did't get solution. When i use this line ==><sj:head jqueryui="true" 
         jquerytheme="customTheme" 
         customBasepath="template/"/> jquery validation error message is not getting. Please help me solve my problem

Comment: @RajeshK, sorry, there's not much more I can do if you don't know how to inspect the HTML as it's rendered in the browser source.  I also never said to remove the `<head></head>` tags... I only said that you'll need to edit your theme's `head.ftl` file.

Comment: Sparky i knw inspecting element in browser in order to get solution wht i need to do pls guide me

Comment: In my struts2 project does't have head.ftl template then how should i edit that template

Comment: @RajeshK, I don't know anything about Struts2 other than what I'm linking to above.  However, if you show your HTML source code as seen by the browser, I can point to what parts are broken.

Comment: as you mentioned above jquery-1.7.2.min.js, jquery.ui.core.min.js?s2j=3.3.1,jquery.subscribe.min.js, jquery.subscribe.min.js these plugins automatically loaded. I did't include this plugins it will load automatically

Comment: If you cannot control which plugins Struts2 is loading automatically, then you're stuck.  Manually loading the plugins again with different versions is no good either because you cannot load the same plugins twice.